# How to add a git dependency and implementation in gradle for project in android studio

Tags: android, git, kotlin, gradle

hello i am new to android app development and so far i was trying to make a android app that lets you read and show pdf file inside of the app following some online guides. the main problem comes at the moment i need to import a dependency from github to be able to read and show the files (com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2) i got a bunch of errors some from the the sistem is unnable to locate the files and functions of said dependency and the gradle build is unable to locate the git repo

my project Setings

-kotlin as main language

-Android 8.0 (oreo) as SDK

-Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 as IDE

some solutions i have read is that i have to add "jitpack" first in "allprojects" block of my gradle file to be able to import the dependency

```
allprojects {
        repositories {
            ...
            maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        }
    }
```

my gradle files are as follow

build.gradle.kts (Project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.2" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.0" apply false
}
```

build.gradle.kts (Module :app)

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.pdfviewtest"
    compileSdk = 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.pdfviewtest"
        minSdk = 26
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")

    //dependency I want to add
    implementation("com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2")

    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
}
```

settings.gradle.kts

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()

    }
}

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "Pdfviewtest"
include(":app")
```

in my gradle files there isnt an "allprojects" block
anding add jitpack in the repositories that belong to pluginManagement and dependencyResolutionManagement have not worked
i dont know is there is something that i am doing wrong or if there is a setting i need to modify first. i hope someone can help

Answer (score 1):

you could try this way , at setting.gradle:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

at build.gradle(project level), add jcenter():

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```